# Deploy Google Cloud Functions with in Code Settings from Google Cloud SDK

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy a simple function using Google Cloud SDK. It's simple function like this:

```
exports.newFunction = async (msg, ctx) => {
    console.log('Hello World')
}
```

and deploy it with settings (like region, trigger etc) according to [this link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy).

but I really miss using Functions for Firebase where I can deploy function with settings(in this case, region and trigger) in the code like this:

```
exports.newFunction = functions.region('asia-east2').pubsub.schedule('every 1 minutes')
.onRun(async (context) => {
    console.log('Hello World')
}
```

I know I can still deploy it with firebase SDK, but still, I want to know if Google Cloud SDK provide this. Is there a possible way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

gcloud can't deploy functions written using the firebase-functions module provided by Firebase.  That module, and its API, is specific to deployment with the Firebase CLI.

If you want similar behavior with gcloud, you will have to write your own framework to declare and invoke functions programmatically.  It would not be easy work.